# What's the differences between tf.GraphKeys.TRAINABLE_VARIABLES and tf.GraphKeys.UPDATE_OPS in tensorflow?

Tags: tensorflow

Here is [doc](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/GraphKeys) of tf.GraphKeys in tensorflow, such as `TRAINABLE_VARIABLES`: the subset of Variable objects that will be trained by an optimizer.

And i know `tf.get_collection()`, which can find some tensor that you want.

When use `tensorflow.contrib.layers.batch_norm()`, the parameter `updates_collections` default value is `GraphKeys.UPDATE_OPS`.

How can we understand those collections, and difference in them.

Besides, we can find more in ops.py.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

These are two different things.

### TRAINABLE_VARIABLES

`TRAINABLE_VARIABLES` is the collection of *variables* or training parameters which should be modified when minimizing the loss. For example, these can be the weights determining the function performed by each node in the network.

**How do variables get added to this collection?** This happens automatically when you define a new variable with `tf.get_variable`, unless you specify

```
tf.get_variable(..., trainable=False)
```

**When would you want a variable to be untrainable?** This happens from time to time. For example, occasionally you will want to use a two-step approach in which you first train the entire network on a large, generic dataset, then fine-tune the network on a smaller dataset which is specifically related to your problem. In such cases, you might want to fine-tune only part of the network, e.g., the last layer. Specifying some variables as untrainable is one of the ways to do this.

### UPDATE_OPS

`UPDATE_OPS` is a collection of *ops* (operations performed when the graph runs, like multiplication, ReLU, etc.), not variables. Specifically, this collection maintains a list of ops which need to run before each training step.

**How do ops get added to this collection?**
By definition, update_ops occur outside the regular flow of training by loss minimization, so generally you will be adding ops to this collection only under special circumstances. For example, when performing batch normalization, you want to recompute the batch mean and variance before each training step, and this is how it's done. The mechanics of batch normalization using `tf.contrib.layers.batch_norm` are described in more detail in [this article](http://ruishu.io/2016/12/27/batchnorm/).

Comment: "ops which need to run after every training step" - Do you mean 'after' or 'before'? Normally UPDATE_OPS, in the context of batch normalization, is used in a `tf.control_dependencies` that heads a `with` block containing the actual training op that updates the trainable variables. Do you actually mean 'before'?

Comment: Thanks @Syncopated! You are right. Edited the answer to reflect this.

Answer (score 0):

Disagree with the previous answer. 
Actually, everything is an OP in the `tensorflow`, the variables in the `TRAINABLE_VARIABLES` collections are also `OPs`, which is created by the OP `tf.get_variable` or `tf.Variable`.

As for the `UPDATE_OPS` collection, it usually include the moving average and moving variance, crated in the `tf.layers.batch_norm` function. These ops can also be regarded as variables,  as their values are updated at each training step, just like the weights and bias.

The main difference is that the `trainable` variables participate the process of back `propagation`, while the variables in the UPDATE_OPS not. They only participate the inference process in the test mode, so so gridients are computed on these variable in the `UPDATE_OPS` .