# tf.control_dependencies(tf.get_collection(tf.GraphKeys.UPDATE_OPS)) in tensorflow

Tags: python, tensorflow, deep-learning

What is purpose of `tf.control_dependencies(tf.get_collection(tf.GraphKeys.UPDATE_OPS))` in tensorflow?

With more context:

```
    optimizer = tf.train.AdamOptimizer(FLAGS.learning_rate)
    with tf.control_dependencies(tf.get_collection(tf.GraphKeys.UPDATE_OPS)):
        train_op = optimizer.minimize(loss_fn, var_list=tf.trainable_variables())
```

Comment: Is this code in batch_normalization?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The method `tf.control_dependencies` allow to ensure that the operations used as inputs of the context manager are run before the operations defined inside the context manager.

For example:

```
count = tf.get_variable("count", shape=(), initializer=tf.constant_initializer(1), trainable=False)
count_increment = tf.assign_add(count, 1)
c = tf.constant(2.)
with tf.control_dependencies([count_increment]):
    d = c + 3
with tf.Session() as sess:
    sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())
    print("eval count", count.eval())
    print("eval d", d.eval())
    print("eval count", count.eval())
```

This prints:

```
eval count 1
eval d 5.0 # Running d make count_increment operation being run
eval count 2 # count_increment operation has be run and now count hold 2.
```

So in your case, each time you run the `train_op` operation it will first run all the operations defined in the `tf.GraphKeys.UPDATE_OPS` collection.

Comment: But what is a real practical use case of using `tf.control_dependencies`?

Comment: If you rename the variable `a` into `count`, make it non-trainable and rename the operation `b` into `increment_count` you could have a counter on the number of times you called the operation `d`.

Comment: Here is a good use case, i.e. control the order in which tensors are evaluated: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53725512/what-is-the-sequence-for-tensorflows-session-to-run-a-list-of-tensors

Answer (score 3):

If you use for example `tf.layers.batch_normalization` the layer will create some Ops, that need to be run every training step (update the moving average and variance of the variables).

`tf.GraphKeys.UPDATE_OPS` is a collection of these variables and if you put it in the `tf.control_dependencies` block, these Ops will get executed before the training op is run.

https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/layers/batch_normalization

Comment: Any other use cases except batch_normalization?

Comment: Not that I know of. By a quick search in the TF docs, it looks it might be used in the `tf.metrics` package, but it looks these functions only return an update op and you need to place it in the collection manually.

Comment: Some more context on `tf.GraphKeys.UPDATE_OPS` https://stackoverflow.com/a/48261613/1179925